# Debug a makefile in Java

Tags: java, makefile

I have no idea how to troubleshoot errors that arise while a project is building.  Any suggestions for dealing with this?  Language is Java.

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `org/zeromq/ZMQ$Context.class', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Per below suggestion got this output from `make -d`:

```
Considering target file `org/zeromq/ZMQ$Context.class'.
File `org/zeromq/ZMQ$Context.class' does not exist.
Looking for an implicit rule for `org/zeromq/ZMQ$Context.class'.
Trying pattern rule with stem `ZMQ$Context.class'.
Trying implicit prerequisite `org/zeromq/ZMQ$Context.class.cpp'.
Trying pattern rule with stem `ZMQ$Context.class'.
Trying implicit prerequisite `org/zeromq/ZMQ$Context.class.o'.
Trying pattern rule with stem `ZMQ$Context.class'.
Trying implicit prerequisite `org/zeromq/ZMQ$Context.class,v'.
...
Must remake target `org/zeromq/ZMQ$Context.class'.
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `org/zeromq/ZMQ$Context.class', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

So, looks like make isn't smart enough to look in `ZMQ.java` for `ZMQ$Context.class` 's definition.  Is this a problem with my version of `make` or a problem in the makefile the library owner supplied me?

Comment: Suggestion: Do you know who wrote the makefile? You should try contacting that person. You are wasting time looking for an answer here - this is going to be case-specific

Comment: It's a library function.  I'm googling around for anyone who has had the same problem.  There exists a ZMQ.java file with a static private class called Context so I would expect ZMQ$Context.class to be produced.  So, I don't know how to debug this, and would like to become better at troubleshooting this type of problem on my own before picking up the phone and contacting the library writer.

Comment: Generally speaking, Java project uses Apache Ant as a build tool... With Make, such a job is much more difficult even if not impossible.

Comment: Make is a language. Just like c. Just like java. Makefiles are programs. You ***can not debug a program without the code***. Just saying.

Comment: Where does this class name come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure a short question. The answer may be `man make`.

You will discover `-d` option for generic debug Make verbosity or even `--debug=FLAG` to reduce output to less verbose debug levels.

In your specific case, Make try to find the source file required to generate `org/zeromq/ZMQ$Context.class` and the Makefile rule may not be clever enough to guess it must be compiled from `org/zeromq/ZMQ.java`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a start.  Question edited to show output from make -d.